# PHP scripts calls another to return image data when receiving 0 bytes

Tags: php, http-headers, mime-types

There are 2 PHP scripts, each on a separate server:

`get_image_data.php`: The first one is visible to the outside world and acts as a 'bridge' to the second, with some additional logic to log things to a database.

The script calls the secnodn one, which is not accessible from the external world.

`get_image_from_file.php`: The second script takes the input (GET) which identifies a image file and returns the content.

We cannot let the first script access the image files directly.

When testing calling the get_image_from_file.php script directly returns the image perfectly.

But when we call this from the bridging script get_image_data.php we get 0 bytes returned.

The script has the following:

```
// get_image_from_file.php - on the hidden server with direct access to files

$content = file_get_contents ( 'some path' );

header("Content-Type: image/png");
header("Content-Length: " . filesize('some path'));
echo $content;
```

The bridging script is as follows:

```
// get_image_data.php - on the public facing site and no direct access to files, so calls 
// get_image_data_from_file.php to get the data.

$file_id = 'xxxx';
$file_name = 'ffffff';

$content = file_get_contents( 'http://addr/get_image_from_file.php?fileid=' . $file_id);
$size = strlen($content);
$type = 'image/png';

header("Content-length: $size");
header("Content-type: $type");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$file_name");
//ob_clean();
//flush();
echo $content;
```

I think the issues is the `header` commands conflicting between the 2 cases, but I've experimented and I cannot get the get_image_data.php script to work.

Comment: So `$content` is empty in `get_image_data.php`? If so what does `file_get_contents` return, is the request over server (`http`) or file system (`/`)?

Comment: Yes. `$content` is empty in `get_image_data.php`. In `get_image_data.php` the `file_get_contents` call is `http` (to an internal address pointing to `get_image_from_file.php`), but in `get_image_from_file.php` the `file_get_contents` is to a filesystem path.

Comment: `get_image_from_file.php` should call as `http` as well

Comment: Turned out to be a path problem in calling file_get_contents. Code above was OK. Resolved now.